# .htacess allow from local and deny all except one user agent

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, access-rules

I have local page. All I want to access it from my phone and my computer. There is no chance to have static IP.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !MyUserAgent [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from MYLocalIp
```

These codes are not working together. How can I use them together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This all can be done in single rewrite rule itself:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !MyUserAgent [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=11.22.33.44
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Where `11.22.33.44` is your local IP address.